# Why the last Ubuntu updates ask to remove libcupsys?

Tags: updates, printing

Today I decided, f
rom the update manager to bring the last updates in my Oneiric but that's the problem:

[image]

Probably, the upgrade of Cups ask to me to delete libcupsys2 and my printer's drivers.
Somebody knows a solution to resolve this problem?
Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

well I do not understand italian ;). I suggest to try what the following command

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

does output. I think you have some broken dependencies already present in your system. If so, the command mentioned will already ask to remove the packages.

After uninstalling the package with the broken dependencies you can install it again and hopefully the brolen dependencies are also repaired.

Greetings from Switzerland, Michael

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simply to wait a while, refresh your sources, and try to install the update again.